# Does Dafny support "proof by construction"?

Tags: proof, dafny

Suppose I have a method that computes something:

```
method Difference(a: nat, b: nat) returns (c: nat)
  ensures a + c == b || b + c == a
{
  ...
}
```

Never mind the implementation for now. If I *can* implement this method in Dafny, that means that for all possible arguments *a* and *b*, there must be some return value *c* that fulfills the postcondition.

In other words, the body of the method is a **constructive proof** that:

```
forall a: nat, b: nat :: exists c: nat ::
  a + c == b || b + c == a
```

But [Dafny is not convinced](https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/8XUwf):

```
method Difference(a: nat, b: nat) returns (c: nat)
  ensures a + c == b || b + c == a
{
  c := if a > b then a - b else b - a;
}

method Main() {
  assert forall a: nat, b: nat :: exists c: nat ::  // error: assertion violation :(
    a + c == b || b + c == a;
}
```

Is there a way to use this kind of reasoning in Dafny?

Comment: as assert should be followed by a boolean expression, I think we should have some assumption for values of a,b and c which is Difference(a,b). I guess this goes to Boogie level of translation on what to trigger in forall.

Comment: The boolean expression being asserted is `forall a: nat, b: nat :: exists c: nat :: a + c == b || b + c == a` (split over two lines).

Comment: One problem is that Dafny won't let you call Difference in a ghost context, such as a `forall` statement or `lemma`. That problem seems directly related to my question here. There may be another problem related to triggers and this particular example, but my question is not about this one method—it's about a kind of proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valéry's answer is a good trick for cases where existence is proved by a lemma. You can also extend the trick to "hint inside a `forall`" using Dafny's `forall` *statement*, like this

```
forall a: nat, b: nat
    ensures exists c: nat :: difference_property(a, b, c)
{
    var c := difference(a, b);
    assert difference_property(a, b, c);
}
```

which proves the `forall` *expression*

```
forall a: nat, b: nat :: 
    exists c: nat :: 
        difference_property(a, b, c)
```

For Jason's other question about using proper methods in proofs, Dafny does not support this. Indeed, I think it makes sense that it is not supported, since methods can have effects on the heap, for example. Thus, the construction of some witness may in principle depend on allocating state or even modifying existing state. Internalizing that effect into the logic is fishy and would change Dafny's nature.

Answer (score 2):

This does the trick: wrap the property in a predicate, and prove the `exists` in a lemma, so that you can hint the verifier with an `assert`.

Maybe there is some way to hint inside a `forall` as well.

```
predicate difference_property(a: nat, b: nat, c: nat)
{
    a + c == b || b + c == a
}

function difference(a: nat, b: nat): nat
{
    if a > b then a - b else b - a
}

lemma main(a: nat, b: nat)
    ensures exists c: nat :: difference_property(a, b, c)
{
    var c := difference(a, b);
    assert difference_property(a, b, c);
}
```

Comment: This is a nice technique, and I'll be using it. I appear to have accidentally asked two questions. The question I meant to ask is about "methods as proofs".

Comment: Try ghost methods or function methods, or even function signatures (without body) e.g. `function difference(a: nat, b: nat): (c: nat) ensures c == if a > b then a - b else b - a`.

Comment: Under Curry-Howard correspondence, the return type of a function _is_ an `exists` and the function body is its proof. To use the proof and get a witness, just call the function!

Comment: This question is about methods. "Try ghost methods or function methods" won't work if the algorithm uses internal state or calls other proper methods.